# PHP7 compatibility test

Tags: php-7.1

After checking our code with php7mar there are some entries
in the report that are similar to the following:

```
  #### /includes/classes/class.shopdb.php
* funcGetArg
 * Line 206: `                  $args = func_get_args();`
```

When I check the specified file and the code, this is what I have:

```
    if(func_num_args() > 1) {
        $args = func_get_args();
        foreach($args as &$item)
            $item = ShopDB::quote($item);
        $query = vsprintf(str_replace('?', '%s', $query), array_slice($args, 1));
    }
```

I really don't see anything wrong here...
Anyone else?

Comment: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/606/how-the-php-functions-func-get-arg-and-func-get-args-changed-from-php-5-x-to-php-7-x

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, func_get_args should work fine in php7.
Still have a few lines in the php7mar report that I don't understand:

- variableInterpolation
- Line 370:                                 `return $this->smarty->registered_plugins[$plugin_type][$tag][0][0]->$function[1]($new_args, $this);`
- Line 441:                                 `return $this->default_handler_plugins[$plugin_type][$tag][0][0]->$function[1]($new_args, $this);`
- Line 481:                         `return $this->smarty->registered_plugins[Smarty::PLUGIN_COMPILER][$tag][0][0]->$function[1]($args, $this);`
- Line 63:           `$this->$row[0] =  $row[1];`
- newOperatorWithReference
- Line 53:     `* Remember to use ampersand when creating an OLE object ($my_ole =& new OLE();)`